# ListView inside View prevent Scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to wrap a `<ListView>` with few other `<View>` inside a `<View>`. When I do this I can't able to scroll the **whole list** of ListView (I can scroll a bit which will bounce back even if it not yet reached the bottom of the list). The simplest render view which will have issue is this.

```
        <View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderList.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}/> 
        </View>
```

The above code will work fine if I don't have it wrapped with that single `<View>`

You might ask why I need to wrap ListView inside a View thats because I want to have some other view inside that view , which then will happen `JSX adjasend error` if I don't wrap them inside a `<View>`.

```
        <View>
            <View>bla bla bla</View>
            <View>bla bla bla</View>
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderList.bind(this)}
                style={styles.listView}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}/> 
        </View>
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add style  `flex : 1` on the `<View>` which wrap `<ListView>`

```
    <View style={{ flex : 1 }}>
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderList.bind(this)}
            style={styles.listView}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}/> 
    </View>
```